# Typescript - Observable response type change if i call catch

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm trying to create a service that handle technical errors but i'm facing an issue.
The type of the returned item change if i do a catch:

```
Observable.of(1, 2, 3).subscribe(
  item => {}, // item type is number
  error => {}
);

Observable.of(1, 2, 3).catch(error => {
  // do something
  throw error;
}).subscribe(
  item => {}, // item type is number | {}
  error => {}
);
```

Is there a way to keep the item type as only a number when catching an observable ?

Context:
I'm trying to share the handle of web services throught multiple service:

- WepAPI.Service will handle technical error (404, 500, ...)
- ComponentRelated.Service will handle functional process and error
- Component will handle data transformation specific to the UI

Maybe i'm not doing it the good way, any advice/sample would be aprreciated.

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html)

> Remember to return an observable from the catch function

Don't throw an error in the error function, the purpose of the .catch is to provide a fallback value without breaking the stream. this fallback must be another observable (while you will still get the content of the observable on the first argument of the subscribe).

```
Observable.of(1, 2, 3).catch(error => {
  const fallbackValue: number = 42;
  Rx.Observable.of(fallbackValue);
}).subscribe(
  item => {}, // item type is number
  error => {}
);
```